# Is there a way to store locally pdf files from an api response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I've been trying to save pdf files locally from an api response. Here´s what i´ve tried so far.

```
 const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      responseType: 'blob',
    },
  };

  const response = await axios.get(
    apiURL,
    config,
  );

  fs.writeFile(
    `filename.pdf`,
    response.data,
    (err) => {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      else console.log('file saved succsefully');
    },
  );
```

I don't get any errors, but it doesn't write the file either.

Here is what i get from the response.data

[image]

Comment: Please add enough code to the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`responseType` should not be in the `headers` config.

You could also write the response as a stream to the file using `responseType: "stream"`.

```js
const config = {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
  responseType: 'stream'
};


const response = await axios.get(apiURL, config)

const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('filename.pdf')

response.data.pipe(fileStream)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Blob` is not a valid `data` type for `fs.writeFile`.

Try the following:

```js
const config = {
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
  },
  responseType: 'blob'
};

const response = await axios.get(
  url,
  config
);

const arrayBuffer = await response.data.arrayBuffer();

const buffer = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer);

const filePath = `./${response.headers['content-disposition'].split('=')[1]}.pdf`;

await fs.writeFile(filePath, buffer).then(() => {
  console.log('file saved succsefully');
}).catch((err) => console.log(err));
```